# Does the Sun twinkle?

Tags: the-sun, orbit, amateur-observing, mass, visualization

Does our solar system have enough bodies in orbit to appear to twinkle to another distant solar system viewed from the side?

[image]
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_asteroid-discovering_observatories

[image]
https://phys.org/news/2018-11-nasa-lucy-sky-asteroids.html

Comment: While it looks crowded, it's really quite empty when drawn to scale.   Jupiter, for example, when it crosses the sun's path it blocks about 1% of the sunlight.   That's not very much when viewed from another solar system.

Comment: What userLTK said. The average distance between asteroids is around a million km, about 2.5 times the distance between the Earth & the Moon.

Comment: @PM2Ring this would also include the Oort cloud and Jupiter Trojans and thickest of the asteroid belt would only cause the Sun to be dimmed 1%?

Comment: @PM2Ring No answers in the comment box.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While objects blocking the sun may have an effect on the twinkle if viewed on another planet, a twinkle is mainly caused by the effect the atmosphere of a planet has on the light, or something interfering with the light that is passing to your eyes.

From Wikipedia's article on [Twinkling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twinkling):

> Twinkling, or scintillation, is a generic term for variations in apparent brightness or position of a distant luminous object viewed through a medium. If the object lies outside the Earth's atmosphere, as in the case of stars and planets, the phenomenon is termed astronomical scintillation; within the atmosphere, the phenomenon is termed terrestrial scintillation.[2] As one of the three principal factors governing astronomical seeing (the others being light pollution and cloud cover), **atmospheric twinkling is defined as variations in illuminance only.**
>
> **Stars twinkle because they are so far from Earth that they appear as point sources of light easily disturbed by Earth's atmospheric turbulence**, which acts like lenses and prisms diverting the light's path. **Large astronomical objects closer to Earth, like the Moon and other planets, encompass many points in space** and can be resolved as objects with observable diameters. With multiple observed points of light traversing the atmosphere, their light's deviations average out **and the viewer perceives less variation in light coming from them.**

Comment: I think the black hole aspect of something else blocking is extremely rare.   The atmospheric cause of twinkling is the primary reason.

Comment: @userLTK right.

Comment: Agreed.  I'd define "twinkle" as the high-frequency component of delta brightness, and planetary occultation as mid-frequency,  and (maybe) stellar output variation as low-frequency.

Comment: @uhoh I updated the answer on the binary systems and removed the black hole part.

Comment: @Max0815 looks great, thanks!

Comment: @Muze do you need any clarification?